# how does the Image Gallery form get populated in Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento, image-gallery, magic-methods, adminhtml

I can see that `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content::getImagesJson()` and `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\helper\gallery.phtml` are responsible for putting the image data into the browser via the `Product.Gallery` prototype class.

However, I can't track down where the image collection gets set on the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content` block.  I'm assuming its via a magic setter somewhere in the controller or layout, but I can't track it down.

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content::getImagesJson()` has

```
$value = $this->getElement()->getValue();
        if(count($value['images'])>0) {
            foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
```

so something is populating the `element` attribute of that block.

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content` seems to be instantiated by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery::getContentHtml()` but that doesn't set any attributes on the block.

I can see that `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::afterLoad()` populates the attribute with an array that matches the structure that the `Product.Gallery` Javascript is looking for, but I'm still a little mystified as to where the Attribute gets tied to the rendering Block.

I think I need a diagram to keep this tangled web straight in my head!

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say;

> ... seems to be instantiated by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery::getContentHtml()` but that doesn't set any attributes on the block.

But `getContentHtml()` looks like this:

```
/**
 * Prepares content block
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContentHtml()
{

    /* @var $content Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content */
    $content = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')
        ->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_helper_form_gallery_content');

    $content->setId($this->getHtmlId() . '_content')
        ->setElement($this);
    return $content->toHtml();
}
```

It clearly sets the `element` for `$content` to `$this`, which is the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery` object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was right in front of me. The `media_gallery` attribute in `eav_attribute` defines `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media` as its backend class which does the `afterLoad`magic-setter.

Still not exactly sure where the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery` gets attached to the product edit screen Tabs, anyone know?

Comment: A quick [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) shows the gallery tab gets instantiated in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes::_getAdditionalElementTypes()`.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - yeah I saw that too, but I'm not seeing where that method gets called...

Comment: That method is called by it's inherited `_addElementTypes()` method which in turn is called by it's descendent - `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Simple` - when preparing the form.

Answer (score 0):

> Still not exactly sure where the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery gets attached to the product edit screen Tabs, anyone know?

I found out that this is done in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs`

Look at line 74:

```
            $this->addTab('group_'.$group->getId(), array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
                'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                    'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                        ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                        ->toHtml()),
            ));
```

If you commented it out this code the "Images" tab will disappear.

There is a lot of "magic" in this gallery, I have open another discussion about it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740995/how-to-include-magento-image-gallery-in-a-custom-module-backend

I hope it helps :)